# Keep HTML tags inside text file

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
foreach ($changed as $value){
            $langstr.= "\$lang['".$value['key']."']="."\"".htmlentities($value['val'])."\";"."\n";
        }
        write_file($filepath, $langstr);
```

Right now it writes the text ignoring the html tags.How can I write a text with html entities to a file ?the $value['val'] is the value posted from textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it writes the text ignoring the tags'?

Comment: could you add the corresponding input and output that you have in the file for the code above.  And what you desire the output to be.  There is some confusion here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Keep HTML tags in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911209/php-keep-html-tags-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
write_file($filepath, strip_tags($str,"<b>"));
```

You can add whatever tag you would like to keep (comma-seperated)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

When I read the OP's post, I read it that somehow their data was filtered.  Or rather html that was submitted in their form was stripped from the string written to the text file.  And therefore I concluded it must be happening on the form input, and suspected the XSS filter.

However, I tested this with CI 3.1.5, with the filter globally turned on.  And implicitly through the input method.  And it was NOT stripping html from the text string.

Further I could use `write_file()`, with a html string and it was also being passed through raw.

OLD ANSWER IGNORE:

Turn off CodeIgniter's XSS filtering.

```
$test = $this->input->post('result', FALSE);
```

This is under the assumption that, you have the XSS filter turned on globally or loaded somehow.

I read that this feature is deprecated, and it's better turned off (then you don't need the second parameter set to false).

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

However you may wish to still filter the text entering the file if you have untrusted data.  You could use another tool for this or use strip_tags as other answers suggest.

Comment: I read it, that the OP wants raw text in the file, and there is something stripping his tags.  Which I can only assume is some filtering done from the CI_Input class.

Comment: I can't really ascertain what codeigniter's XSS filter filters, and whether or not it filters html.  The manual states it's no good for filtering html attributes, and to use html_escape for that.   I've also read the default is to not have this global filter turned on.  And it can't be relied upon.  So if anyone has better knowledge of this function please chime in.  And apologies if this is a red herring.

Comment: I tested it, and the XSS filter does not filter html tags.

Answer (score 0):

For the tags only, make use of [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

or you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with the `ENT_QUOTES` flag. or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php),

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);

echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

> `ENT_QUOTES`   Will convert both double and single quotes.

As per the documentation,

**Note:**

- In case of an ambiguous flags value, the following rules apply: When
  neither of `ENT_COMPAT`, `ENT_QUOTES`, `ENT_NOQUOTES` is present, the
  default is `ENT_COMPAT`.
- When more than one of `ENT_COMPAT`, `ENT_QUOTES`, `ENT_NOQUOTES` is
  present, `ENT_QUOTES` takes the highest precedence, followed by
  ENT_COMPAT.
- When neither of `ENT_HTML401`, `ENT_HTML5`, `ENT_XHTML`, `ENT_XML1` is
  present, the default is `ENT_HTML401`.
- When more than one of `ENT_HTML401`, `ENT_HTML5`, `ENT_XHTML`, `ENT_XML1` is
  present, `ENT_HTML5` takes the highest precedence, followed by
  `ENT_XHTML`, `ENT_HTML401`.
- When more than one of `ENT_DISALLOWED`, `ENT_IGNORE`, `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` are
  present, `ENT_IGNORE` takes the highest precedence, followed by
  `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`.

**Reading Material**

[Is htmlentities() sufficient for creating xml-safe values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822774/php-is-htmlentities-sufficient-for-creating-xml-safe-values)

Comment: I think he wants the raw output of the HTML tags and not the encoded one

Answer (score 0):

```
$test=$this->input->post('result');
$str="my test";
foreach ($test as $value){
$str.= $value['val'];
}
write_file($filepath, "<b>");
write_file($filepath, $str);
write_file($filepath, "</b>");
```

either hardcode like above   or use htmlspecialchars

```
$test=$this->input->post('result');
$str="my test";
foreach ($test as $value){
$str.= $value['val'];
}
write_file($filepath, htmlspecialchars($str));
```